# How to get total count and list of records using the Entity Framework 6 SqlQuery

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-6, dynamicquery

I have some complex requirement where user can filter result based on several parameters. I have used Entity Framework SqlQuery to prepare the dynamic query. So in the application i wanted to display 
- Total No of Records available by applying the filter
- Display only 25 (pagination records using the same filter)

I do not want to get all the records from the database server to app server. i have to get only 25 records and total no of filter result using the same query.

following are the code to get the result from database:

```
using (Entities dbEntities = new Entities())
                {
                    var resultQuery = dbEntities.AllResources.SqlQuery(searchQuery, parameters.ToArray());
                    int count = resultQuery.Count();
//Here i am getting an error "The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection."
                    var searchResult = resultQuery.Skip(startRecord).Take(pageSize).ToList();
                }
```

What i have tried:
i have called to separate query like

```
//For getting total count
int totalRecords = 0;
                using (Entities dbEntities = new Entities())
                {
                    var countQuery = dbEntities.AllResources.SqlQuery(searchQuery, parameters.ToArray());
                    totalRecords = countQuery.Count();
                }
```

For getting paged records (25 rec)

```
using (Entities dbEntities = new Entities())
                {
                    var resultQuery = dbEntities.AllResources.SqlQuery(searchQuery, parameters.ToArray());
                    var searchResult = resultQuery.Skip(startRecord).Take(pageSize).ToList();
                }
```

But still error is not resolved. However i have cloned the parameters and then clear that param but no luck.

```
SqlParameter[] parametersCount = new SqlParameter[parameters.Count];
parameters.CopyTo(parametersCount); 
var countQuery = dbEntities.AllResources.SqlQuery(searchQuery, parametersCount.ToArray());
```

Comment: I think the parameters are your less problem. If you hover the `Count`, `Skip` and `Take` methods you'll see that they are mapped to `Enumerable` methods, not `Queryable`, which means they will be executed *after* materializing the query result in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **either re-create `SqlParameter` instances, or** (if you are using the stored procedure) you can just **define one of the parameters you are passing to SP as an output one** to retrieve the total records count in addition to the paginated records.

You will find some tips [here](http://makhaai.blogspot.ru/2014/08/how-to-get-stored-procedure-output.html) (the post uses the simple parameter values, but you can use `SqlParameter` object as well).